# App runs on iphone only once then xcode cannot find the Iphone anymore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So this is the issue I am having. When I plug in my iphone xcode recognizes the iphone and everything checks out fine. I can then build my project and run it on the device. It works fine, for the first time. If I build the project again and try to run it again xcode gives this error:

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Also instead of my phone name in the top left it changes to iOS device.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your versionnumber of your iPhone/iPod/iPad. If you've set up the Deploeyment target to high like if you have an iPhone with IOS5 and the target is IOS6 this error occurs. You may had simply to *decrease* the value to something under your device IOS versionnumber or the same **BUT** not above the value otherwise it **won't** work.

Go to your project > traget> deployment target > set to something that you want.

Thats all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ya this has already been done, I made sure that it was IOS6, and my iphone has IOS6. It turns out though that it was just a bad cord. If i use my other cord it works fine so.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. It turns out that my Cord was bad. Once I switched out the cord everything worked great.

Thanks for any help anyone gave.

Comment: actuallly only I did but...hey! :D